# Magento2: PHP Error Deprecated Functionality:

Tags: php, magento2

can somebody help me with this?

I'm getting this error when I try to setup:di:compile with Magento

Deprecated Functionality: Optional parameter $ids declared before required parameter $checkedCat is implicitly treated as a required parameter in /home/seedsa
t/public_html/magento244/app/code/MGS/Fbuilder/Helper/Data.php on line 162

Line 162 looks like this:
public function getTreeCategory($category, $parent, $ids = [], $checkedCat)

Answer (score 0):

This happens on the recent versions of PHP. The error says that optional parameters must be at the end of the argument list of the function. Not in the middle, because it doesn't make sense to have optional parameter then a mandatory one.

Upgrade Magento or change the function:

```
getTreeCategory($category, $parent, $ids = [], $checkedCat = null)
```

Comment: then it needs to change also where is this function called